# SQL Query Practice with ER Diagram

Tags: sql

This question has been haunting my life. Consider the figure.

[image: [Click here for Figure]]

1. Write the SQL statement(s) that will find the average hours of all employees per project.
2. Write the SQL statement(s) that list all the projects where employee with Employee Number 1251 is involved with an assignment, but not as a manager.

This is what I have ..

Query 1:

```
SELECT AVG(ASSIGN_HOURS) 
FROM ASSIGNMENT a, PROJECT P 
WHERE p.EMP_NUM=a.EMP_NUM;
```

Query 2:

```
SELECT * 
FROM PROJECT P, ASSIGNMENT A 
WHERE P.EMP_NUM<>1251 
    AND A.EMP_NUM=1251;
```

Please help!

Comment: What's your approach? What do you have so far?

Comment: This is a task but not a question. What is your question when working on your tasks?

Comment: SELECT AVG(ASSIGN_HOURS) FROM ASSIGNMENT a, PROJECT P WHERE p.EMP_NUM=a.EMP_NUM; for 1

Comment: SELECT * FROM PROJECT P, ASSIGNMENT A WHERE P.EMP_NUM<>1251 AND A.EMP_NUM=1251; for 2

Comment: what is the identification column for manager in your database tables?

Comment: Not entirely sure. All the info I have I put.

Answer (score 2):

Below are queries which will solve your purpose.

Query for 1

```
SELECT prj.proj_num
    ,asg.emp_num
    ,avg(asg.assign_hours)
FROM Project prj
INNER JOIN Assignment asg 
    ON prj.proj_num = asg.proj_num
GROUP BY prj.proj_num
    ,asg.emp_num
```

[SQL FIDDLE FOR FIRST QUERY](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/795a0/7)

Query for 2

```
SELECT prj.proj_num
      ,prj.proj_name
      ,asg.* 
FROM Project prj
INNER JOIN Assignment asg 
    ON prj.proj_num = asg.proj_num 
WHERE asg.emp_num = 1251 
    and prj.emp_num <> 1251
```

[SQL FIDDLE FOR SECOND QUERY](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/795a0/5)

Assumption made based on your comments - that emp_num column in Project table will have manager emp_num.

NOTE: **TESTED AND WORKS**

Comment: @MarmiK Thanks, i am learning SQL and you have raised my confidence!

Comment: I have just reformatted your answer to make it niche. :) though welcome.

Comment: @leah - Please mark it as answer if you feel i have helped you! :)